# Magento Exploit - Buddys ID in my home page

Tags: security, magento1.9.3

I'm a new web developer hired in house and it's only my 3rd day on the job and I found what looks to be a Exploit. The script is this here,

```
<div id="buddys" style="position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0.001;z-index:10;">
<center><a href="http://www.******" title="porno">porno</a> - 
<a href="http://www.******" title="sohbet hattı">sohbet hattı</a> - 
<a href="http://www.*****" title="porno izle">porno izle</a><center>
</center></center></div>
```

Problem is I have no idea where this is coming from and I'm not sure how to find the exploit. My version of magento is 1.9.3 Can anyone help me find out what this is actually?

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

1. `ssh` to your magento folder
2. First search all files with `find` command:

   ```
   find . -type f -exec grep -iHn --color=always 'buddys' {} \;
   ```

   If you find a file open it up and remove the code. Then clear magento cache.
3. If nothing found in step 2 dump your database and search inside it to find configuration setting, CMS page or block where this exploit resides:

   ```
   mysqldump -uUSERNAME DATABASE -p>db.sql

   grep -in 'buddys' db.sql
   ```

   Once you find the line in db.sql go to that line (open db.sql with vim editor for example) and see what it is: configuration entry, CMS page or block or something else. Then go to magento backend and change it.

Hackers often paste malicious code to cms blocks or Misc HTML code in *System > Configuration > Design > Footer > Misc HTML*. It happened a few times to the shops I maintain.

Comment: Note: This will help you find and remove it, but it won't prevent it from happening again. Change all your admin passwords, check MageReport, compare your code against the equivalent M1 version to find anything else hiding out, and look for other guides on hardening/securing your Magento install.